# "CM_Get_DevNode_Status" function declaration unit in Delphi2010

Tags: delphi, configuration

I need to use `cfgmgr32.h` in Delphi2010. Is any unit file(.pas) for to use the function

```
`**CM_Get_DevNode_Status**` in Delphi2010. Please help me.
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you need from `CfgMgr32.pas` from the [JEDI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) project.

Comment: Yes, I download full `JEDI Project`, then I got CfgMgr32.pas. Thanks so much my dear brother.